# Can a HTML5 aside tag contain headers and articles?

Tags: html

What is the best way to seperate sections of text within an aside tag? Can it contain headers and articles or does this go beyond the aside tag definition?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element):

> Content model: Flow content, but with no `main` element descendants

with `main` referring to the HTML5 element `main`. So technically headers and articles (and pretty much [every HTML element you can think of](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) - list too long to post here) can be used within `aside`.

However, regarding its content it's probably better to not overload the element with too much information on its own, but rather use it to display or point to some additional information:

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.

That's why I wouldn't really expect `article` elements in there.

Regarding your question about how to seperate sections within the `aside` element it pretty much depends on what you want it to contain. If the different sections are not really related to each other it's perfectly okay to use multiple `aside` elements. If they are related you may just want to choose the HTML you'd choose elsewhere.